# Bilateral and Adaptive image processing in Python

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

I am in the process of porting these functions from MATLAB to Python using OpenCV module.

```
im = imbilatfilt(im, degSmooth, sigmaSpatial); %bilateral filter with dof and spatial_sigma

thresh = adaptthresh(im,0.5,'NeighborhoodSize',2*floor(size(im)/16)+1); % adaptive threshold
```

I have the above two functions in MATLAB and found the equivalent functions in Python with OpenCV module. How do I define the degree of smoothing, spatial sigma in OpenCV function for the same?
And, for adaptive threhold how do I define the Sensitivity and Neighbourhood size for the equivalent OpenCV function?

Here is what I tried with no results.

```
b = cv2.bilateralFilter(image, 0.5, sigs, sigs)
threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_grey, 0.5, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 375, 501)
```

Any advise is helpful.

Comment: With regards to the adaptive thresholding function. `NeighborhoodSize` in the Matlab function is similar to the `blockSize` parameter in the opencv function. Both define the size of the neighborhood that is used to calculate a threshold value.